# Loading Dialog on MP3 Media player prepare()

Tags: java, android

I am new one in android development. I have a mp3 audio player code which play mp3 from url. I want to show loading dialog box when media player is buffering on prepare

Here is my Code I show a dialog on prepare but it continuous run and cannot play mp3.
I have no idea where i define smp.setOnPreparedListener. Please tell me that can i define this in play function or outside play function. Please Help Me here is my code. Thanks in Advance please

//Play MP3 Function

```
public void  playSong(int naatindex){
    // Play song
    try {

        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(naatpaths[naatindex]);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mywidget);  
        tv.setSelected(true);  // Set focus to the textview
        tv.setText(naattitles[naatindex]);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);
        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();            
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and here is my mp.setOnPreparedListener code

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, 
                        "Loading Title", "Loading Message");
   mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
           if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
              progressDialog.dismiss();
           }
            mp.start();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In playSong(), you call :

```
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

If you directly start the player it would crash because it may be not ready to play. Try this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(naatpaths[naatindex]);
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                  progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
});
mp.prepareAsync();           //this will prepare file a.k.a buffering
songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
songProgressBar.setMax(100);
// Updating progress bar
updateProgressBar();
```

If it still fails to play, check the stream url. It might be dead. Also try logging the state of the player. Check the stacktrace for any exceptions too.